# Is there any mechanism to obtain userProfile info from user storage in WSO2 Esb from code?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Salute! As example: I have a user in named  "tesUser" with userProfile, in which there is a specific field "email" that I want to get as <property> in my <inSequence>.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFFYY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create DataService based on Datasource: WSO2_CARBON_DB. Use schema *PUBLIC* and tables *UM_USER*, *UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE*. In the UM_USER you have um_id and userName, in the UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE you get the email by um_id. Now you can write own query to join that data and expose as service, and use internally.

Another way is to use existing internal service `https://localhost:9443/services/UserProfileMgtService?wsdl`. For expose that wsdl you need to set `<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>` in carbon.xml. There is *getUserProfiles* operation which will give you what you want.

And last way i think is to write own [Class Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Class+Mediator) which will use *JDBCUserStoreManager* for retrive that information.

None of these solutions are easy ... but I have listed them in order of the easiest ones, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you a lot! But I think I still have to use localEntries to map info about specific user. I guess it will be cheaper. I hope some day we will set up APIM...